# alternative method for thread.sleep()

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

"In the page, there are several side menus. I need to click on a specific menu item, which leads to a different page depending on whether the user is new or existing. After that, I need to validate the content. Once done, I return to the dashboard page, click on another menu item, and validate elements on a different page. Currently, we are using `Thread.sleep()` as the waiting mechanism, but it takes a considerable amount of time for the pages to load. Are there any alternative methods or concepts we could use?"

proper code for waits

Comment: [Selenium's waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: Can you show some code of what you are doing?  Thanks